# Exchange Calendar Sync can't edit turns reminders on

Tags: calendar, exchange, active-sync

I have synced my Galaxy S II with exchange 2010 server. It has imported all my calendar events as expected, however it has set a reminder on all of the events. For example, in Outlook I have public holidays in my calendar with no reminder, however on my phone these are imported with an Alarm "On Time". Since these are all day events, the alarm goes off at midnight.

Does anyone know a way way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved by upgrading to Ice Cream Sandwich